# How can I fix printing to Brother MFC after upgrading to macOS Sonoma?

Tags: macos, printing, sonoma

I have upgraded two computers to Sonoma - one from Ventura that still can print and another from Catalina that can not.

Printing fails over the wireless connection or by attaching the printer directly by USB. The printer is Brother model MFC-L5750DW. It claims the printer is offline, and keeps "looking for printer."

How can I address the failure to print from the second Mac?

Comment: So it's a shared printer.  How is it shared?

Comment: Did you try to remove the printer from Settings and add it again?

Comment: The "Settings" reply held the secret. I changed the default printer to a different listing of the same printer and now have printed two documents - hope it sticks.

Answer (score 0):

My similar, but not exact, printing issue to a shared printer was resolved after adding my Epson ET-3850 printer to my Wi-Fi network and cycling the power to my Airport Time Capsule Router.

I could print without issue from my Mac Studio M1. It was connected to the printer via USB. The Mac Studio was configured to share the printer allowing everyone to print, however, seemingly overnight I could no longer print from my iMac M1. Both Macs were on my local network via Wi-Fi. Both were running Sonoma 14.2.1, although I did upgrade the OS on each Mac 1 time during the troubleshooting period.

Neither Mac ever had an issue connecting to the internet over the Wi-Fi network or with screen sharing over the network. Never before have I had a printing issue with a Mac using a shared printer.

After lots of internet research and aggravation, I added my printer to my Wi-Fi network and cycled power on my Airport Time Capsule Router a couple of times. Then I made sure of a tight fit on all cables associated with the modem and Time Capsule. Finally printing from the iMac was restored.